# Sass Parent Selector

Tags: sass

I'm not sure the best way of phrasing this, but through examples.

My desired output is:

```
.parent-class2.parent .child {
  color: red;
}
```

This is the sort of syntax that I'm using.

```
.parent {
  .child {
    .parent-class2.& {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is almost there. There are two things to take note of:

1) SASS doesn't like redundant periods `.` in selectors (malformed selectors):

- With `.parent-class2.&` the period before `.&` is redundant since `&` = `.parent .child`
- Notice that having the extra period before `.&` would incorrectly compile to
  `..parent .child`

2) To use the ampersand in the middle of a selector without any spaces, you will have to wrap it with a string interpolation `&` → `#{&}` for SASS to evaluate it.

Here's the fixed version:

```
.parent {
  .child {
    .parent-class2#{&} {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&#{&}` selector ("`&`" is the parent, so we select "the parent of the parent").

As mentioned in https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-11

> The interpolation brackets #{ } are needed as two touching ampersands are invalid Sass.

You can also take a look at `@at-root` selector which could be usefull in your case.